# COM accessible data class c#

Tags: c#, com, data-class

My COM interface:

```
[ComVisible(true)]
public interface IPersonAccessor
{
    Person GetById(int id);
}
```

The Person Class is a simple data class as below:

```
public class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
}
```

Do I need to do anything else for the Person class(putting attributes on person class etc) so that C++ code can access its properties?

Comment: Yes, it also has to be [ComVisible(true)].  Writing an interface for it is good style and the COM way, return IPerson instead.  If you don't then you have to also apply  [ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.AutoDual)] to the class so the C++ code can use early binding.  Helps a lot to leverage the #import directive.  You'll need it, writing COM interop code in C++ is pretty cruel.

Comment: @HansPassant thanks for your reply. One additional thing, to return a collection from a COMVisible method, I can use the ICollection type. Can I use an ICollection of IPerson as a parameter of a COMVisible method?

Comment: @VictorMukherjee ICollection doesn't seem to be ComVisible, so I don't think you can. Either way, the more common way is to just use an array, which the C++ code will see as a SAFEARRAY.